# mongodb atlas cluster golang insert struct slice interface context canceled, current topology

Tags: go, mongodb-atlas

When I insert a set of documents into a MongoDB Atlas collection I get the following error message:

**2021/12/23 09:37:03 server selection error: context canceled, current topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Servers: [{ Addr: cluster-attitude-shard-00-00.o7pjk.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown }, { Addr: cluster-attitude-shard-00-01.o7pjk.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown }, { Addr: cluster-attitude-shard-00-02.o7pjk.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown }, ] }**

I use the next code:

```
interfaz_slice := ToInterfaceSlice(students)

_, err := coleccion.InsertMany(ctx, interfaz_slice)
```

The function "ToInterfaceSlice" recieve a slice of structs and return a slice of interface

I do not understand where I am making a mistake

Thanks in advance

New part of question:

**File fragment "main.go":**

```
func main() {

    var students []data.TypeStudent

    absPath, _ := filepath.Abs("data/students.csv")

    students = data.LeerFichero(absPath)

    data.ConectaBD()

    data.InsertaColleccionEstudiantes(students)

}
```

***File fragment "students.go":***

```
type TypeStudent struct {
    FirstName string `bson:"first_name" json:"first_name"`
    LastName  string `bson:"last_name" json:"last_name"`
    Class     string `bson:"class" json:"class"`
}

func ToInterfaceSlice(lista []TypeStudent) []interface{} {
    iface := make([]interface{}, len(lista))
    for i := range lista {
        iface[i] = lista[i]
    }
    return iface
}
```

**File fragment "basedatos.go":**

```
func ConectaBD() {

    cliente_local, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI(cadena_conexion))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    ctx, cancelar = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    err = cliente_local.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer cancelar()

    mongo_cliente = cliente_local.Database("attitude")

    log.Println("[+]Connected to MongoDB Atlas")

}

func InsertaColleccionEstudiantes(students []TypeStudent) {

    coleccion = mongo_cliente.Collection("students")

    interfaz_slice := ToInterfaceSlice(students)

    log.Println("[+]A slice of interfaces are inserted directly into MONGODB")

    _, err := coleccion.InsertMany(ctx, interfaz_slice)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

Comment: The error is not in the Golang client code, but in the MongoDB cluster you're running. Have you tried connecting with mongo shell and executing the query?

Comment: I could connect with mongosh: [link](https://asciinema.org/a/yOOQuwS9fDuskyjJLJ4lCoQgl)

Comment: I watched the video, you should run the same query from mongo shell, and please share the rest of the code, the connection handler, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information is not sufficient. Check if `IP` is whitelisted or not. Also specify which context you are using. You can try with `context.TODO()`.

I tried and it's working fine.

Make sure your connection is successful. Also close the connection using `defer`.

Here is the sample code you can try with this :

```
client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), options.Client().ApplyURI(uri))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err = client.Disconnect(context.TODO()); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    // begin insertMany
    coll := client.Database("insertDB").Collection("haikus")
    docs := []interface{}{
        bson.D{{"title", "Record of a Shriveled Datum"}, {"text", "No bytes, no problem. Just insert a document, in MongoDB"}},
        bson.D{{"title", "Showcasing a Blossoming Binary"}, {"text", "Binary data, safely stored with GridFS. Bucket the data"}},
    }

    result, err := coll.InsertMany(context.TODO(), docs)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

For better understanding please refer this link : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-golang/master/source/includes/usage-examples/code-snippets/insertMany.go

Comment: your fragment of code works. I have to have any wrong in my code

Comment: Amazing, just to add context.TODO works:_, err := coleccion.InsertMany(context.TODO(), interfaz_slice). Thank you so much and merry christmas!!!